# How to change auto numbering to existing auto numbering sequence in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

In Cash Sales (AR304000 screen) i want to set it's auto numbering sequence from invoice number sequence to payment number sequence.

i tried the following code but to no avail. saving new sales throws an error. see attached photo for the error.

[image]

here is my DAC code:

```
public class ARCashSaleExtension : PXCacheExtension<ARCashSale>
{
    #region RefNumber

    [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(**PX.Objects.AR.ARPayment.refNbr**))]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reference Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [ARPaymentType.RefNbr(typeof(Search2<ARCashSale.refNbr,
        InnerJoinSingleTable<Customer, On<ARCashSale.customerID, Equal<Customer.bAccountID>>>,
        Where<ARCashSale.docType, Equal<Current<ARCashSale.docType>>,
        And2<Where<ARCashSale.origModule, NotEqual<BatchModule.moduleSO>, Or<ARCashSale.released, Equal<boolTrue>>>,
        And<Match<Customer, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>, OrderBy<Desc<ARCashSale.refNbr>>>), Filterable = true)]
    [**ARPaymentType.Numbering()**]
    [PXFieldDescription]
    public String RefNbr
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use AutoNumberAttribute instead of ARPaymentType.Numbering attribute.

```
[AutoNumber(typeof(ARCashSale.docType), typeof(ARCashSale.docDate),
                new string[] { CashSale, CashReturn },
                new Type[] { typeof(ARSetup.paymentNumberingID), typeof(ARSetup.paymentNumberingID) })]
```

Besides, I can't see any reasons to use ARPaymentType.RefNbr attribute instead of ARCashSaleType.RefNbr attribute.

One more thing: from my point, it's better to use Cache_Attached on graph extension for rewriting attributes on one field instead of creating DAC extension.

Here is an example of Graph extension with CacheAttached:

```
public partial class ARCashSaleEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<ARCashSaleEntry>
{
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)] // that attribute is here to keep all attributes of base field except the one that should be replaced.
    [AutoNumber(typeof(ARCashSale.docType), typeof(ARCashSale.docDate),
            new string[] { ARDocType.CashSale, ARDocType.CashReturn },
            new Type[] { typeof(ARSetup.paymentNumberingID), typeof(ARSetup.paymentNumberingID) })]
    public virtual void ARCashSale_RefNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
    }
}
```

To learn more about cache_attached events see T200 training

Comment: how do i use the cache_attached approach on graph extension to solve the problem? could you provide some example? and what page on the acumatica t documentation that may help on cache_attached. thanks.